# Why does Tyler say "60 seconds till CRI"?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In *Fight Club*, the character of Tyler is a product of Narrator’s personality disorder. With support from Project Mayhem members, Tyler brought Narrator's friend Marla to the abandoned building against her will. In the same abandoned building, with her hands tied to a chair, Narrator begs Tyler to stop Project Mayhem, but Tyler refuses.

> Tyler: What do you want? Your shitjob back? Fu.king condo world,
> watching sitcoms? Fu*k you! I won't do it.
>
> Narrator: This can't be happening.
>
> Tyler: It's already done, so shut up! 60 seconds till **CRI**.

[image: Proof this dialogue exists - screenshot of subtitles from Netflix]

What's the meaning of "CRI"?

Exactly 2 hr 12 min is the timestamp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*From much later comments it appears Netflix were guessing. A movie of this age would not have been subtitled originally, so someone has been tasked with doing it after the fact.*

Let's call it a 'misheard lyric' or [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) like they do with pop songs that people guess & blog the words to, without actual reference to the published lyrics.

From a more reliable script & checked against the movie audio…

> "60 seconds. Can you see alright?"

[Link to a more reliable script](https://web.archive.org/web/20210717055309/https://jsherry.edublogs.org/files/2012/08/FC_script-1lv8zpi.pdf) - I still don't know whether this is direct from source or not, but it matches what is actually said in that scene & is spelled correctly ;)

BTW, the misheard lyric is actually what is in the subs file of the dodgy downloaded mkv version I got hold of to check against;) Not all subs in dodgy downloads are straight from the studio. Often they're generated by people guessing at what was said.

Scene on YouTube at

but no subs. You can compare the audio, though.

Comment: Dodgy downloads in this case = Netflix.

Comment: Then Netflix were guessing;) I very much doubt a movie from 1999 was subtitled at the time, it's been done after the fact.

Comment: @Tetsujin Closed captioning has been required in the US since 1998 for broadcasts.

Comment: @Legion600 - still doesn't mean the original production company wrote them.

Comment: it doesn't even sound like `Can you see alright` not even close.

Comment: I don't know why this one has gained so much interest right now, three years after it was posted, but I linked to a script that says that is the line & other than 'can you' is very buried the 'see alright' is clear as day to my ear. That aside - if anyone can make any sense whatsoever of the mondegreen "CRI" I'd be really glad to hear your take on it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've marked this question for reopening. It never should have been shut

Comment: I have the answer, I look forward to the question being reopened so I can finally settle this ;)

Comment: "*A movie of this age would not have been subtitled originally*" - Uh, cinematically released movies have been provided with Closed Captioning since the 1970s. There's no need to guess with subtitles if you're an actual distributor.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy The question has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

> Cranial Rectal Inversion

Or, *to have one's head up one's bottom*.

[On Urban Dictionary cira 2003](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rectal%20cranial%20inversion)

[On Pintrest](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/231513237069148012/)

[On LinkedIn cira 2015](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/your-managers-suffering-cranial-rectal-inversion-david-grebow/)

Most often I see this term deplyed as a politically or ideologically motivated attack which is in-keeping with Tyler's motivations but I will not post more links as I don't want to drive traffic to trolls, but a quick web search will reveal all.

Tyler is expressing that his plan is going akin to *sticking "the system's" head up it's own backside*.

It's a throwaway line, and to be honest I think it has been deployed incorrectly, but the line is absolutely `60 seconds till CRI` and this is what `CRI` is.

(I'll add this though, it's a surprisingly bad bit of sound design in an otherwise amazingly constructed film. The clunk of the wheelybox perfectly obscures the line. I'll verify next time I'm at the (my) cinema, but I suspect if you watch this on a mutli channel set-up with only the centre channel switched on it will clear up the dialogue nicely)

Comment: Medically speaking, it's an AER (*Acute Encephalonis Rectalis*) :D

Comment: This seems like a fair guess, but can you offer any specific evidence that this is what he means?

Comment: I can produce as much evidence as the other answer here, except Netflix and the Blu-ray agree with us that it is indeed CRI and Cranial Rectal Inversion is exactly the kind of nonsense you'd expect from Tyler :)

Comment: *And you drew the short stick, 'cause YOUR head is....*